# Create table as select statement primary key in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, sql-scripts

Is it possible to specify which is the primary key on creating table as select statement? My aim is to include the declaration of primary key on the create table not modifying the table after the creation.

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers
AS (SELECT company_id, address, city, state, zip
  FROM companies
  WHERE company_id < 5000);
```

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: @Abra im using SQL Developer

Comment: _SQL Developer_ is an IDE. What Oracle database version are you using? Is it 11g ? Is it 12c ? Is it 18c ? From the [Oracle SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sql-developer.html) Web page: _Oracle SQL Developer is a free, integrated development environment_. In other words, _Oracle SQL Developer_ is **not** a database.

Comment: @Abra Currently im using 10g.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's possible. You would need to specify columns explicitly:

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers (
    company_id primary key, 
    address, 
    city, 
    state, 
    zip
) 
AS 
  SELECT company_id, address, city, state, zip
    FROM companies
    WHERE company_id < 5000;
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ffb2c44dd229502c76854907f1e4feb3)

**Note**: in this case primary key constraint will be given a system-generated name. If you want it to have a custom name you'd have to execute `alter table suppliers add constraint <<custom constraint name>> primary key(<<primary_key_column_name>>)` after executing(without `primary key` specified) `CREATE TABLE suppliers..` DDL statement.

Comment: Is it also applicable when using create table statement in "as with" ?

Comment: @absolute Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.You can try referring below example.

```
create table student (rollno ,student_name,score , constraint pk_student primary key(rollno,student_name))
as
    select empno,ename,sal 
    from emp;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create Suppliers table explicitly and if any column have primary key in companies table, then copy that structure from companies table.

Or

Create a same column defining primary key that you want and copy that column from companies table!